# Equating number types in r

Tags: r

I am posting two small codes. Both give different answers and I am not able to understand why this is happening and what is the work around of this problem.

```
i=3
a=i*0.1
a==0.3
FALSE

i=2
a=i*0.1
a==0.2
TRUE
```

Comment: I was just reading that @nicola. Very interesting read!

Answer (score 0):

You can round a, to get more consistent result:

```
i <- 3L
a <- i*0.1
round(a, 1) == 0.3


i=2L
a=i*0.1
round(a, 1) == 0.2
```

This may be occurring due to data type mis-match.